# How can I find the function that throws an error message in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging

Let's suppose I want to use IDA Pro to debug a Windows PE64 application that always throws an error message at a specific point when being run. What steps would I have to take to find the specific function in the code of the application that throws the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find the string of the error message in the binary (Hotkey: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, Search for binary). If the auto analysis worked well, the string should be annotated with all functions that reference the string, and you should be able to jump to the instructions that refer to the message using the cross references popup (Hotkey: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)